# jaxb2 maven plugin and configuration inside execution tag

Tags: configuration, maven, jaxb2

I try to use JAXB2 maven plugin to generate java code from a bunch of .xsd files. If I try to generate from all xsds in a single execution I'll get `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: 'root' is already defined`. I cannot modify the xsd files so I need to generate each independently. I found the following pom configuration to achieve that:

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>jaxb-Execution1</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals><goal>xjc</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${jaxbSchemaDirectory}</schemaDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${jaxbGenerateDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            <staleFile>${jaxbGenerateDirectory}/.staleFlagExecution1</staleFile>
            <bindingDirectory>${jaxbSchemaDirectory}</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingFiles>bindings1.xml</bindingFiles>
            <schemaFiles>schema1.xsd</schemaFiles>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>jaxb-Execution2</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals><goal>xjc</goal></goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${jaxbSchemaDirectory}</schemaDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${jaxbGenerateDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            <staleFile>${jaxbGenerateDirectory}/.staleFlagExecution2</staleFile>
            <bindingDirectory>${jaxbSchemaDirectory}</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingFiles>bindings2.xml</bindingFiles>
            <schemaFiles>schema2.xsd</schemaFiles>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

But this is not working. The problem is that configurations are not read from inside of the execution block. Why is that? I am using maven 2.2.1.

Comment: Have you defined the properties like `${jaxbSchemaDirectory}` in your pom.xml?

Comment: @flash Yes I have. I also entered directories without any property placeholders to test. The problem is that those configurations inside execution blocks are ignored by the plugin.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when I tried to run the plugin using:

```
mvn jaxb2:xjc
```

A workaround for me was using:

```
mvn generate-sources
```